# Fewer observations & larger documents vs More observations & smaller documents

Tags: classification, nlp

Let's suppose that I have a dataset of 1000 documents.

Each document is a restaurant review (so relatively short text) and it has labels {Negative, Indifferent, Positive}.

Let's suppose that the dataset has 600 positive reviews, 200 indifferent reviews and 200 negative reviews.

I want to train a classifier to classify a review as Negative or Indifferent or Positive based on the text of the review.

I am not thinking about using any word embeddings for now so I will probably use a TF or TF-IDF model (even though this may be a bit off topic for current question).

Let's suppose that in my case I split (in a stratified way) my dataset into a training set of 800 observations and into a test set of 200 observations.

My question is the following:
Is it better to have 800 separate documents in my training set or to merge these documents based on its categories/labels and create 3 very big documents?

There 800 separate documents of any of the 3 labels or 3 big documents of each of the labels is the best way to go and why?

My question stems from the fact that in the latter case if for example I do TF-IDF then this will be applied based on different categories/labels since each document will be about a category/label.

On the other hand, if I do (as we usually do actually) like in the former case then the TF-IDF will be categories/labels-agnostic and I do not know this helps things.

Is the answer simply that this an interesting but pretty bad idea because in this way you simply massively decrease the number of the observations with which the model/algorithm is trained and so you make much harder for him to figure out how to successfully classify things?

Answer (score 1):

> There 800 separate documents of any of the 3 labels or 3 big documents of each of the labels is the best way to go and why?

The first thing you need to think about in any ML problem is: what is an instance for the problem? In other words, what is going to be the input for which you want a prediction at the end of the process?

Imagine you train your model with 3 big documents, one of each label. Then the input for such a model is a big set of documents with the same label. So it can only predict a label for a set of documents sharing the same label. This means that somehow you need to have the labels before applying your model... difficult isn't it? :)

This is why in this case an instance must be a single document. It's the job of the learning algorithm to learn to discover the label based on the instances, and for that it needs many instances of each possible label.

> On the other hand, if I do (as we usually do actually) like in the former case then the TF-IDF will be categories/labels-agnostic and I do not know this helps things.

This is where there is a confusion: the TF-IDF weights are not supposed to encode the label in any way, they represent the importance of a particular word in a document. The learning algorithm will use this information **for all the words**, that is it's going to learn the difference between when the word *delicious* has a high TF-IDF and when the word *disgusting* has a high TF-IDF (for instance).

> Is the answer simply that this an interesting but pretty bad idea because in this way you simply massively decrease the number of the observations with which the model/algorithm is trained and so you make much harder for him to figure out how to successfully classify things?

That would be true as well, but the main issue is the one I mentioned above: you won't be able to provide the same kind of input when you apply your model on your unlabeled data.

Comment: So in a concise way what you are saying is that it is much better to train your model on observations of the same "form" (e.g. of the same number of words approximately) as your test data will be? And except for that you do not see anyother principal problem etc? You can also see and possibly answer a similar question of mine (https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52929/split-large-documents-into-many-smaller-ones) which I posted a bit ago.

Comment: It's not only better, it's the only way which makes sense. As an experiment you can try both, you will see that one of the models is just useless.

Comment: I am not saying no this (I think this too at the end) but I am asking why is this exactly)? (By the way, upvoted your answer)

Comment: So as you said the difference was massive (with using tf-df and random forest at least). In the case where I split the documents in multiple smaller documents then in my classification project the accuracy was 94% whereas in the case where I did not split the text then it was 0%.

Comment: However, to be honest I would like a theoretically well-founded explanation of why this happens. My intuition, as yours, was that something like this would happen but I just want to a good explanation of that.

Comment: Afaik there are only experimental validations for TF-IDF weights, but maybe there are also theoretical explanations. You can explore the literature in information retrieval, there's certainly a lot about it. What's important to understand in your case is that TF-IDF is completely unsupervised: it is used to represent documents, it's not related to the labels.

Comment: Ok but my point is not really about TF-IDF but about the topic of my post "Fewer observations & larger documents vs More observations & smaller documents". But yes at least in the case of TF-IDF it would be good to really know why the one approach works and not the other.

Comment: Oh right sorry I got confused. This is a very fundamental point of any supervised ML: your goal is to find a function f such that f(x) = label y for any input instance x. You train a model on many instances x in order to approximate this function. This function will (in theory) work for any instance x similar to the ones in the training data, but is unlikely to work with anything different. Here the kind of instance (big document) you use as training is completely different from the one you use for testing, this is why the model doesn't work.

Comment: additionally your training set contains only 3 instances, so your model is very likely to overfit.

Comment: Ok. So regarding the first reason it is also what I also mentioned at my first comment here (and I agree with you). Regarding the second reason I would like a bit more elaborate explanation. Basically the data are exactly the same since I do not use anything more with any number of instances (3 or 100 or 10k) so what is the difference (in a well-founded explanatory way)?

Comment: if the training set contains only one instance with label y, then the model cannot distinguish which features for this instance are random and which are associated with the label. If there are many instances, the model will see which features are "in common" for this label and discard the ones which vary independently from the label.

Comment: Yes at conceptual level this must be the explanation. Perhaps I would also like a more technical one.

Comment: You need to read, any decent introduction to ML will address this kind of question. I would recommend looking at the standard algorithm for decision trees C4.5, its logic is quite intuitive and you can simulate it manually with a small example.

Comment: Haha I know that I can read it somewhere as everybody in general could find an answer to his/her StackExchange question at a book...But if this was the best answer that we could get from the StackExchange then this site would not even exist...

Comment: The reason why I recommended reading is because imho this is not a specific question with a specific answer (which is the format for SE), it's more about the general concept of supervised ML so it's worth reading a detailed chapter about it. But if you think it can be made into a specific question you should ask a new question.

Comment: Hm not sure at all about that. The more general questions are the most popular ones in SE: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832076/what-is-the-difference-between-supervised-learning-and-unsupervised-learning - which is in SO which was supposed to be for very very specialised programming questions. So there is lots of room for "less specific" questions especially on the DS SE.